# How to pass a filtered array while keeping the original unchanged (ReactJS)

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am currently working on a todo list app, and i am trying to implement a function where users can filter tasks based on their completion status (all, completed, or uncompleted). I am trying to use the javascript filter function.'

I have tried using a duplicate array, therefore retaining the original values, and manipulating the duplicate array. However, I could not get the original array to update as the list increases, so i decided to scrap that.

There is a lot of code in my project but i will only copy the ones relevant to the question.

```
const Body = () => {
  let tasks = [
    {
      task: 'Walk the dog',
      completed: false,
      id: Math.round(Math.random() * 100000),
    },
    {
      task: 'Learn ReactJS',
      completed: false,
      id: Math.round(Math.random() * 100000),
    },
  ];

  const [task, setTask] = useState(tasks);

  const addTask = () => {
    let input = document.getElementById('task-field');
    let randomID = Math.round(Math.random() * 100000);
    if (input != null) {
      setTask([...task, { task: input.value, completed: false, id: randomID }]);
    }
  };
  return (
    <div className='body'>
      <Header></Header>
      <Input setMethod={set} inputMethod={addTask}></Input>
      <Tasks tasks={task} display={display} removeMethod={complete}></Tasks>
    </div>
  );
};

export default Body;
```

```
const Tasks=({tasks, display, removeMethod,})=> {
    const  [task,setTask]  = useState(tasks)
    const [display,setDIsplay] = useState(tasks)
    
    const filterFunction=(event)=> {
        let filtered;
        const target = event.target;

        switch(target.innerHTML) {
            case('All'):
                filtered = task
            break;
            case('Active'):
                filtered = task.filter(()=> {
                    return !task.completed
                })

            break;
            case('Completed'):
                filtered = task.filter(()=> {
                    return task.completed
                })

            setDisplay(filtered)
        }
    }
    return(
        <div className="tasks">
            
            {display.map(el=> {
                return (
                    <TaskComponent task={el} removeMethod = {removeMethod} key = {el.id}></TaskComponent>
                )
            })}
            <Footer  method = {filterFunction} ></Footer>
            
        </div>

       
    )

 
}

export default Tasks;
```

so the question is, how do i implement this feauture in ReactJS?

for reference, i am linking a fellow coder's take on the same project : https://nasratt.github.io/frontendMentorSolutions/projects/todoList/

thanks in advance for the help.

Comment: Using a copy for display purposes is fine as long as user interaction updates the state variable. I'm also not seeing any attempt at actually filtering an array in your code.

Comment: @Chris G I did write out some long filtering code, but it was honestly really messy and too confusing for the post, and I was just aiming for another solution or a clean implementation from someone here. Would it be better if i tried to include the code?

Comment: @ChrisG i have included the code in my post.

Comment: A cleaner solution (at least to me) is to use a 2nd state variable to store the filter itself, then to filter a copy based on that.

Comment: `let tasks = [{task: 'Walk the dog', status: 'completed', id: Math.round(Math.random() * 100000),},{ task: 'Learn ReactJS', status: 'active', id: Math.round(Math.random() * 100000)}];` Then only you can filter easily for "Active" otherwiase how you find which task is active or not.  Also use `var completedTasks = tasks.filter((t) => (t.status === 'completed') ? t : '';);`

Comment: @ChrisG if im getting this correctly, then I will be filtering the filtered array?

Comment: Here's example code: https://codesandbox.io/s/peaceful-goodall-z4ecyh?file=/src/App.js

Comment: @ChrisG thanks man, I strayed from the steps a bit and implemented my own touch to it, but your general idea gave me the solution!